# glBufferSubData setting data from 0 rather than supplied offset

Tags: c++, opengl, particle-system, particles

Don't have a whole lot to preface with other than this is being used in/for a particle system that uses transform feedback. There are two vbos that I'm ping ponging between render loops. Here's the initial buffer setup:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &p_vbo_r); glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo_r);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (MAX_PARTICLES*2) * sizeof(particle), &pp[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &p_vbo_w); glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo_w);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (MAX_PARTICLES*2) * sizeof(particle), &pp[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

`MAX_PARTICLES` is set to 262144. `particle` is a struct that contains 2 `glm::vec3` and 2 `GLfloat` totaling to 32 bytes, so my current setup creates buffers that are slightly over 16mb. `pp` is an array containing dummy particle data since straight 0s don't stick out as much when using gDebugger.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo_r);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, total_part*sizeof(particle), pp.size() * sizeof(particle), &pp[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo_w);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, total_part*sizeof(particle), pp.size() * sizeof(particle), &pp[0]);
p.buf_start = total_part;
total_part += pp.size();
```

This happens every time a unique emitter is added to the particle system. All possible emitters in a given scene are added before any rendering is done(currently) and this actually works as intended! It stores the offset used when the emitter was added into p.buf_start when it's done and adds to the running offset.

Now, curiously enough using the same set up later during rendering/execution causes the glBufferSubData command to start from 0 rather than the supplied offset, as so:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo_r);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_sys[i].buf_start * sizeof(particle), pp.size() * sizeof(particle), &pp[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_vbo_w);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, p_sys[i].buf_start * sizeof(particle), pp.size() * sizeof(particle), &pp[0]);
```

This is done in a loop that checks if the buffer needs reset and does so. Any actor may request a reset at any time after rendering, and the buffer does the above code after the frame is finished but before the next frame starts rendering. The first emitter listed works as intended, but any emitter afterwards always overwrites the VBOs from 0 and not from the given offset. Am I unable to overwrite ping-ponging buffers involved in transform feedback? It's been a little tricky trying to figure this one out. Thanks!

EDIT: I've also tried GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW/GL_STATIC_DRAW for the initial buffer setup to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked that the `buf_start` value *itself* isn't just `0` for whatever reason?

Comment: Yup, checked both in MSVC and in printed output for Ultra Sanity™. Values are exactly what I'm expecting/setting in relevant lua scripts.